# Do you call the [dirt at at the bottom of a cup of water] "sediment"

Tags: word-usage

[image]

Can **[sediment]** be used to mean the **[dirt at the bottom of a cup of water]** as the picture above?

If not what would you call it?

When I search the word on Google it only shows up 'stones, rivers'.

Comment: **dregs** goes all the way back to 1300. *(Usually plural) The **sediment** of liquors; the more solid particles which settle at the bottom of a solution or other liquid; **grounds, lees**, feculent matters. Also figurative.*

Comment: How would the OP look the word up in a dictionary, when he doesn't know what the word is? This question is being closed on the grounds that, if we assume that the OP already knows the answer, then he could prove that it's correct. But I presume his problem is that he doesn't know the answer.

Comment: Please give some context - the sentence in which you intend to use the word and what the mixture is. There are several words, **ullage, dregs, grounds, lees, residue, silt, mud, etc**, and these depend on the liquid what the sediment is made of.